# How to grep non consecutive patterns

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How to grep non consecutive patterns...

I run this command.

```
grep -B 1 -A 2 "field-2-value" inputFile.txt |grep -v "field-3"
```

which yields these 4 outputs.

```
  [field-1]xxx[/field-1] 
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2] 
  [field-5]true[/field-5] 
  -- 
  [field-1]yyy[/field-1] 
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2] 
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4] 
  -- 
  [field-1]zzz[/field-1] 
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2] 
  [field-5]false[/field-5] 
  -- 
  [field-1]mmm[/field-1] 
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2] 
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]
```

I am only interested in the 2nd and last results that have field-2 and field-4 values:

```
 
  [field-1]yyy[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]

  [field-1]mmm[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]
```

The inputFile.txt looks like this:

```
[RECORD id="1"]
  [field-1]xxx[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-3]hello[/field-3]
  [field-5]true[/field-5]
[/RECORD]
[RECORD id="2"]
  [field-1]yyy[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-3]hello[/field-3]
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]
[/RECORD]
[RECORD id="3"]
  [field-1]zzz[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-3]hello[/field-3]
  [field-5]false[/field-5]
[/RECORD]
[RECORD id="4"]
  [field-1]mmm[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-3]hello[/field-3]
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]
[/RECORD]
```

I am almost tempted to write a shell script to run two sets of operations: First generate a file that has these outputs for each file that contains these results.  And then remove block of lines that don't have field-4.
Help!

Comment: Looks like I can accomplish this by `grep -B 3 "field-4-value" inputFile.txt | grep -v "field-3"`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne '
   /field-2-value/!{h;d;}
   H;n;n;/field-4/!d;H;g;s/$/\n/p
' inputFile.txt
```

We are rejecting all lines that are not containing /field-2/ but storing them in hold. (Only the last one gets to be saved)

So when we do see /field-2/ line, we append it to hold, skip over next line, then check whether the next-to-next line contains /field-4/. It it doesn't we drop it OTW we append it to hold, then bring over the hold and print it after adding a trailing newline, for the sake of separating out the records printed.

---

## Results:

```
  [field-1]yyy[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]

  [field-1]mmm[/field-1]
  [field-2]field-2-value[/field-2]
  [field-4]field-4-value[/field-4]
```